# Don't store anything in the databases until all the steps are completed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api

I want to make a wizard UI with multiple forms and submission. I make a API call at each submission. If one of the form failed or user sign out in the middle, I want it to revert everything back in the database but I also store their progress. Is something like this possible?

I was thinking of having a `metadata` table where I store JSON data for the forms after each API call

`metadata` table structure

```
| apicall             | data          | method  | email       |
| ------------------- |:-------------:|:-------:| -----------:|
| /api/organization/1 | {json: data}  | POST    | abc@abc.com |
| /api/role/1         | {json: data}  | POST    | abc@abc.com |
```

and once all the steps are done, run through that table and call all those api's to store data in proper tables.

Is there a better way to do it? I was also thinking of just adding a column `inprogress` flag. But there's a lot of legacy code that's using those tables regardless of `inprogress` column.

Comment: Add an active flag to the tables. When they approve the changes you make all of them active.

Comment: I can't do that. Lot of legacy code is using those tables too.

Comment: Use sessions, local storage or any other method to store the raw data somewhere safe for the duration of the session. Why would you even ask the user to fill the form over multiple pages? Just put everything in one form and present it in a clear fashion so that it doesn't hurt the UX.

Comment: are you using react/vue where you could store the state?

Comment: You could use browser storage or cookies to hold that data until the last page the user has to fill in, then send it all at once on the last page.

Comment: Browser storage or session would get deleted when user signout.

Comment: If possible do all database-related changes for intermediate form steps in separate/temporary db/tables. Then move/apply those changes to main db in one transaction in final step. Rollback transaction on failure.

Answer (score -1):

You have two main options:

- Use either local javascript storage and send everything at the last step as a request.

or

- Use $_SESSION variable to store data and process it in the last step. Make sure that your scripts start with session_start(); or you will not have access to your $_SESSION.

The last option would be easier to achieve.